# Is there value in unit testing auto implemented properties

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd, arrange-act-assert

It seems exceptionally heavy handed but going by the rule *anything publicly available should be tested* should [auto-implemented properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) be tested?

**Customer Class**

```
public class Customer
{
    public string EmailAddr { get; set; }
}
```

**Tested by**

```
[TestClass]
public class CustomerTests : TestClassBase
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void CanSetCustomerEmailAddress()
    {
        //Arrange
        Customer customer = new Customer();

        //Act
        customer.EmailAddr = "foo@bar.com";

        //Assert
        Assert.AreEqual("foo@bar.com", customer.EmailAddr);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What happens if you switch from auto-implemented properties to something entirely different? The test only seems redundant because you know the implementation - which you should not consider when writing tests.

Of course, this depends on the likelihood of your actually changing the implementation any time soon.

Comment: If that were to happen, though, you would do it by writing a test first right?  So then it would be tested.  At least if your doing TDD that would be the way it would work.  We all know that folks don't always write their tests first.

Comment: +1 for the regression aspect. It's an auto property today but tomorrow it may need modification to support new class features etc...

Answer (score 10):

I generally consider any code that is not performing an action to be not worth testing.  This typically means that I don't test properties (auto-implemented or not) because they are just setting or returning a value.

This will change if the getter or setter of a property performs some sort of "work", like possibly returning one of two (or more) values based on the state of some other field/property/whatever.

If you have not seen it, I highly recommend [Roy Osherove's](http://weblogs.asp.net/rosherove/) [book on Unit Testing](http://artofunittesting.com/).  It addresses all sorts of "what to test and when" type questions, including this one.

Comment: Testing an auto-property is testing the framework, not your code: there is no code logic to verify. And if you end up adding code behind the property, you should see the test coverage go down, which will indicate that it's now time to test that property.

Comment: Its even simpler than seeing test coverage go down...as I commented in the other response, if you change the code so it is doing something other than an auto-property, that change should be driven by a test, so you will at that point be testing that change in functionality.

Answer (score 1):

It depends if you're testing that an API conforms to an expected set of properties, or if, as you demonstrate, you're just testing accessing and setting the properties.

In the example you give I'd say no.

*Update*

Conforming to expected API; if you're accessing properties indirectly, say in a reflection/dynamic environment, and you use property and method access calls to verify an unknown API conforms to an expected one.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "testing that an API conforms to an expected set of properties"?

Answer (score 1):

Testing setting and getting properties should occur in the context of testing a business function of the object. If there's no business function testing the property then either you didn't need the property or you need more tests. I'd suggest that you add the properties as you add the tests that need them rather than add them prior to writing any tests.

By testing the business function you're treating the code as much more of a black box from the perspective of the unit test. This allows you to switch implementation details underneath with a much smaller impact on the tests. As Refactor is an important (and often overlooked) stage of the TDD cycle this means a lot less code editing. You may also realise that (for instance) the property should not have a public setter and should be assigned by a method that performs validation and other business logic.

Answer (score 0):

Unit testing should be confined to testing functionality that you are implementing in your application.

You should not test API/SDK that your application relies on.  Partly because it's a waste of time (does your company want to pay for you to test X-Third-Party's SDK/API?), and partly because it introduces "noise" into your unit test suite.  The context of your unit test library should be to just test only the code in your application.

Comment: `Customer` is a class we own.

Comment: @ahsteele, true but your test arguably only tests the behavior of the C# compiler.

Comment: @Yishai agreed, in rereading the answer I see what warriorpostman was driving at.